# Network Issue In MS Access Database Application

Tags: c#, ms-access, networking

I have developed an application with MS-Access in c# and want to run it over the network. Here is my `ConnectionString` for client PC.

```
<add name="Connect" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=\\Server-PC\E\AccessDatabase\NextDiag.accdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=mydatabasepassword" providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />
```

The Path of my database on Server PC is `E:\AccessDatabase\NextDiag.accdb`.
I have given full permission to `E Drive` for `Everyone`. But when I am running my application to client machine it's showing the following exception.

`The Microsoft Office Access Database Engine Cannot Open Or Write To The File '\\Server-PC\E\AccessDatabase\NextDiag.accdb'. It is already opened exclusively by another user or you need permission to view and write data.`

What is the issue?
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely either open in exclusive mode on a different connection or open in an Access session, or there may be an invalid lock file (.laccdb) that exists in the same folder.  If that's the case, *with no open connections* on the accdb, just delete it.

Also make sure that the database itself is not corrupt.  Just opening it up in Access should verify that.  You can also verify the open mode at that time as well to help isolate the source of the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have checked all you suggested but everything is fine. One more thing I want to add that some computers on network are working fine.

Comment: So you've tried connecting with no one else in the database and no lock file existing?  Also, is that the proper driver version for the version of Access that the database was created in?  And lastly, is there any security on the database, workgroup or password?